Смысл непонятного заголовка
Насколько грамотно составлен данный заголовок? Не режет ли слух?
То, что имели в виду авторы статьи, ясно.
Вот заголовок:
Умер водитель столкнувшегося с поездом "КамАЗа" под Волгоградом
А вот  отрывок из самой статьи:
Водитель столкнувшегося с поездом "КамАЗа" в Волгоградской области скончался в больнице.
Водитель "КамАЗа", столкнувшегося с пассажирским поездом в Волгоградской области 29 июля, умер в реанимации. Об этом сообщает РИА Новости со ссылкой на администрацию региона.
Здесь определение оторвано от определяемого существительного.

Спешка и всё такое... Проверьте ваш текст, будет смешно.

Что именно вы имеете в виду?

Слух режет, конечно. Заголовки новостных лент уже давно стали издевательством над русским языком. Как вам такое: "Жизель Бюндхен оскорбил повторный выбор экс-мужа футбола вместо детей". ))

Да уж. Неужели нет редакторов?

Что именно вы имеете в виду? – Серж Commented 11 часов назад. //// Кто же кого имел? — возникает вопрос. Проверяйте текст перед отправкой!

Укажите на конкретные ошибки, чтобы было ясно.

Вы проверяете тексты других, а проверить собственный не в состоянии?

Умер водитель столкнувшегося с поездом "КамАЗа" под Волгоградом.
Определяемое существительное "Камаз" в середине  причастного оборота? Разговорный вариант, грамматика и стилистика предложения некорректны.
Правильно:
Умер водитель Камаза, столкнувшегося с поездом под Волгоградом.
Пояснение

Берем исходное предложение:

Под Волгоградом "Камаз" столкнулся с поездом. Под Волгоградом — обстоятельственный детерминант.
Также: Камаз столкнулся с поездом под Волгоградом.

Тогда:  Умер водитель / столкнувшегося с поездом под Волгоградом / "Камаза".

Исправляем стилистику: Умер водитель Камаза, столкнувшегося с поездом под Волгоградом.


